# How to add a column by matching with year?

Tags: r, merge

I am new to R and I am facing an issue as following.
I have two data frames:

```
df1

ID   Date         Name
 1   01/05/2005   Anna
 2   06/04/2009   James
 3   02/07/2002   Sarah
 4   09/10/2000   Natalie
 5   15/11/2007   Benn
```

and my second data frame as following:

```
df2

Year    Income
2000    500
2002    800
2005    200
2007    600
2009    900
```

I want to add the "Income" column in my df1 by matching it with Years. For example as below:

```
df1

ID   Date         Name      Income
 1   01/05/2005   Anna      200
 2   06/04/2009   James     900
 3   02/07/2002   Sarah     800
 4   09/10/2000   Natalie   500
 5   15/11/2007   Benn      600
```

How can I solve a problem like this in R?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a join after creating an 'Year' column in first data

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(df1)[, Year := year(as.IDate(Date, '%d/%m/%Y'))]
df1[df2, Income := Income, on = .(Year)][, Year := NULL][]
```

-output

```
#  ID       Date    Name Income
#1:  1 01/05/2005    Anna    200
#2:  2 06/04/2009   James    900
#3:  3 02/07/2002   Sarah    800
#4:  4 09/10/2000 Natalie    500
#5:  5 15/11/2007    Benn    600
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Date = c("01/05/2005", "06/04/2009", 
"02/07/2002", "09/10/2000", "15/11/2007"), Name = c("Anna", "James", 
"Sarah", "Natalie", "Benn")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2002L, 2005L, 2007L, 2009L), 
Income = c(500L, 
800L, 200L, 600L, 900L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Thank you very much! Worked great :)